# Stochastic integral when one or more limits of integration are random variables...

Tags: integration, limits, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I've revised my question to hopefully be more concise:

Consider a simple Kalman filter that is designed to estimate a single state, the position of a car along a rail, $p$, and a time delay parameter, $t_d$, that is *included in the state vector*. The process model is driven by a velocity input (i.e., the derivative of position). Measurements of the position state occur at a time that either leads or lags the process model (as defined by $t_d$). Note that $t_d$ is a random variable.

Now, I wish to propagate the process model forward in time to next measurement update - this update is predicted to occur at $t + t_d$, but in reality we don't yet know $t_d$ precisely. Thus, we have a situation in which the upper limit of the integration is, in fact, a random variable. This means that the time interval over which we propagate the process model *is a function of $t_d$ in the state vector*.

I have not seen any work that deals with this situation - however, $t_d$ is unknown, and its value affects both the process and measurement model equations.

I am looking for any work on stochastic processes that properly treats the uncertainty associated with a state estimate when the integration bound is a random variable, *and* when one is trying to estimate the mean of that random variable.

Comment: Could be wrong, but couldn't you simply convert such an integral to a more standard type using the characteristic function $\chi$ on a corresponding random interval? Something like this: $$\int_0^X f(X,Y)\,d\mu=\int_0^{\infty}f(X,Y)\,\chi_{[0,X]}\,d\mu. $$

Comment: Oh possibly! This particular problem is new to me - would you have a pointer to a reference that would describe this approach? Thanks!

Comment: An Itô integral typically determines a stochastic process. For example, $$ X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t f(s,W_s)\,\mathrm d W_s. $$ Suppose $T$ is your random time (typically a stopping time), then you are interested in $X_T$. You can then use what you know about stochastic processes evaluated at random times.

Comment: Yes, thanks! What I need is a reference on the evaluation of stochastic processes at random times..

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want out of this exercise. Without knowing more, the best I can tell you is to pick up standard references on stochastic processes/calculus.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reference. It's a common analysis trick, particularly in the Lebesgue world.

Comment: Indeed the problem is somewhat difficult to describe crisply (at this stage).  I would like to estimate the variance of the process - usually this would be done at a definite time t (for an evolving state variable, for example) ... in this case my exact stopping time would be unknown (itself a random variable, which is a delay or lag, effectively).

I can compute the expected stopping time, potentially. My interest is in the influence that the variance in the stopping time (lag parameter) has or should have on the variance of the state estimate. This it tied to filtering theory.